# how to Simulate Ctrl+ c in Delphi

Tags: delphi

is there any way to simulate Ctrl+C command in delphi ? 
the problem is i want that from another application for example copy a text from Notepad after select the target text .

Comment: Send a `WM_COPY` message.

Comment: http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=152642

Comment: @ANdreas i just trying it before and it does not working with others process .

Comment: @Oussaki: yes it does, so you must not be using it correctly.

Comment: When you tried sending `wm_Copy`, was there any text selected in the target window? That's a prerequisite for copying to occur.

Comment: @ROb yeah there is a text selected before doing WM_COPY .

Comment: Could this relate to different process integrity levels?  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772136/sending-wm-copy-from-a-delphi-app-to-another-process-in-windows-7  This might explain why Ken's example works but your situation does not. What's the other app, and have you tried to access an app that you've written (i.e. with the same integrity)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(Let me preface this by saying that using the clipboard for inter-process communication is a bad idea. The clipboard belongs to the user, and your application should only use it as a result of the user choosing to do so.)

If you have text selected in Notepad, this will get the contents into a `TMemo` on a Delphi form (uses just a `TMemo` and `TButton`; add `ClipBrd` to your uses clause):

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NpWnd, NpEdit: HWnd;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  NpWnd := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
  if NpWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    NpEdit := FindWindowEx(NpWnd, 0, 'Edit', nil);
    if NpEdit <> 0 then
    begin
      SendMessage(NpEdit, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
      Memo1.Lines.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Sample of results:

[image: Text copied from Notepad]

If the text is not selected first, send it a `WM_SETSEL` message first. Passing values of `0` and '-1' selects all text.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  NpWnd, NpEdit: HWnd;
begin
  Memo1.Clear;
  NpWnd := FindWindow('Notepad', nil);
  if NpWnd <> 0 then
  begin
    NpEdit := FindWindowEx(NpWnd, 0, 'Edit', nil);
    if NpEdit <> 0 then
    begin
      SendMessage(NpEdit, EM_SETSEL, 0, -1);
      SendMessage(NpEdit, WM_COPY, 0, 0);
      Memo1.Lines.Text := Clipboard.AsText;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: that pretty work good. why i can't ask more questions in this web site ?

Comment: @Oussaki: I have no idea why you can't ask more questions. You should check [meta] for that type of information; it's where questions about StackOverflow's workings, design and guidelines belong. (You saw I answered your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17605421/62576) as well?)

Comment: ahaha Thank you ken you're the best here . (y)

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any way to simulate <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>?

The way to do this is to use the [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx) function of Win32 to synthesize keystrokes. Here is an example:

```
procedure SendCtrlC;
var
  Inputs: array [0..3] of TInput;
begin
  ZeroMemory(@Inputs, SizeOf(Inputs));
  Inputs[0].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[0].ki.wVk := VK_CONTROL;
  Inputs[0].ki.dwFlags := 0; // key down
  Inputs[1].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[1].ki.wVk := ord('C');
  Inputs[1].ki.dwFlags := 0; // key down
  Inputs[2].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[2].ki.wVk := ord('C');
  Inputs[2].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  Inputs[3].Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  Inputs[3].ki.wVk := VK_CONTROL;
  Inputs[3].ki.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
  SendInput(4, Inputs[0], SizeOf(Inputs[0]));
end;
```

Naturally the application which you wish to receive the <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> key stroke will need to have input focus.